# How to get boolean value by executing the Prepared Statement?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am facing a problem. I have no idea is that correct or not.

I am executing a prepared statement query which will return true/false as boolean. When query should executed executed successfully, then it will return true as boolean, but it return as false.

what should I do?

the code is below:

```
String updateListQuery = "UPDATE RECON_EXCEPTION_ETM_DCR SET GROUP_ID = ?, ASSIGN_DT = SYSDATE WHERE RECON_ID = ? AND UPPER(TRIM(REASON_DESC)) <> 'RECONCILED' AND TRUNC(DUTY_DATE) = ? " ;
try{
    conn = Connect.getConn();
    getGroupNameStmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateListQuery);
    
    getGroupNameStmt.setString(1, groupId);
    getGroupNameStmt.setString(2, reconId);
    getGroupNameStmt.setString(3, defFormatDt);
    
    flag = getGroupNameStmt.execute();
     
     flag = true;
    
}catch(SQLException e){
    flag = false;
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    try{
        conn.commit();
        getGroupNameStmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `I have no idea is that correct or not.` we too..Which error you got ?

Comment: 'what should I do???' I dont know either. what is your problem?

Comment: I didn't get any error, Just, I want to know that is there any way, by which I can know that my table is get updated or not???

Comment: Please read the documentation for [`execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()): its return value is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE you can use [ExecuteUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) which returns the number of rows updated, which can be useful when running an update statement. In your case it is not needed, since you know how many records you are inserting.

```
int updateCount=pst.executeUpdate();

if(updateCount>0)
{
    flag=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For updating anything you should use the `executeUpdate` method. Its return type is intege`.
So you just check if:

```
if((getGroupNameStmt.executeUpdate())>0)
{
    do something
}
else
{
    do something
}
```